# "Cioccapiatti" è un termine italiano o solo emiliano?

Tags: regional

Volevo chiedere se il termine *cioccapiatti* è un dialettalismo oppure un termine italiano.

Qui il significato è '*imbonitore*', '*contaballe*', '*ciarlatano*', credo derivato dall'uso dei venditori di piatti che ne millantano la robustezza appunto facendoli cioccare l'uno contro l'altro.

Comment: Penso sia un dialettalismo, ma sicuramente non è solo emiliano, visto che è in uso anche nel dialetto della mia zona d'origine (bassa bergamasca).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Treccani, nel suo [*magazine di lingua Italiana, I nostri lettori cacciatori di parole nuove/6 di Silverio Novelli*](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/articoli/parole/Neologismi_lettori_6.html) riporta:

> Ciocco , cioccapiatti
>
> G. L. ci delizia con queste due voci
> dell'italiano regionale emiliano, con epicentro Bologna e attestazioni
> in varie parti dell'Emilia. Si tratta di parole che hanno precisi
> riscontri dialettali: cioc vale 'scoppio', ciocapiât vale «radicchio
> di campo; tarassaco; scemo, fesso» (L. Lepri, D. Vitali, Dizionario
> bolognese-italiano, italiano-bolognese, Pendragon, Bologna, 20092). In
> particolare, cioccapiatti si dice (diamo la parola a G. L.) di una
> «persona che si vanta doti (nel fare, nell'essere) esagerate, ma che,
> alla resa dei conti, è inconcludente». Nel sito Facebook dedicato a
> cioccapiatti, c'è chi fornisce una lettura interessante dell'accezione
> figurata, molto colloquiale e familiare, della parola, partendo
> dall'accezione di base: «Il cioccapiatti era così chiamato perchè
> quando lo si condiva nel piatto e quando lo si mangiava,scrocchiava (a
> Bologna cioccava). Il cioccapiatti è una specie di radicchio selvatico
> che è molto presente lungo gli argini del fiume Reno. Poi associato a
> persone bugiarde, inconcludenti, false ecc. in quanto sembra una
> verdura pregiata ma in realtà è amaro, duro ed una volta pulito non
> rimane nulla = persona con pochi contenuti. Io la conosco così».
> Cioccapiatti è incluso nel Manuale di lingua e mitologia urbana , il
> che significa che per l'autore del Manuale la voce è propria degli usi
> giovanili. Parola da tenere ben custodita in attesa di un dizionario
> del lessico italiano regionale.

In questo *[Manuale di lingua e mitologia urbana](https://www.bruttastoria.it/dictionary/cioccapiatti.html)* si legge:

> il ***cioccapiatti*** era il ciarliero venditore di piatti al mercato che
> era solito sbattere, cioè "cioccare" piatti di poco valore uno contro
> l'altro per decantarne la robustezza. Di conseguenza il termine è
> venuto ad indicare la persona che millanta crediti o promette
> prestazioni che non si sa se potrà mantenere.

In questo *[Blog degli studenti universitari di Bologna](https://bolognabloguniversity.it/slang-bolognese-tutte-le-parole-un-non-bolognese-deve-conoscere-la-lettera-c/)* si può leggere:

> **cio(c)capiatti** s. m. persona non degna di fede, che racconta storie
> poco credibili, una specie di banfone; “te sei un gran cioccapiatti” ♦
> dal dialetto ciocapiât s. m. (=). Vedi anche ballista

dove il termine viene indicato come appartenente allo "slang" bolognese, quindi come termine regionale.

In Liguria il termine con lo stesso significato sarebbe *contamusse*.

Comment: Quindi, se ho capito bene, si tratta di italiano regionale emiliano.

Comment: @Charo Direi proprio di sì.